# Chemical potential vs derivative of free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, mixtures

Let $x$ be the concentrations of species in a chemical system, and let $G(x)$ be the Gibbs free energy. My understanding is that the chemical potentials should be given by
$$
\mu_k = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x_k}.
$$
Now [Kondepudi and Prigogine](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118698723) seem to say that for an ideal solution,
$$
G(x) = \sum_k x_k\mu^0_k + RT\sum_k x_k\log x_k
$$
(equation 8.4.1 of the second edition, with a slight change in notation, see below). But if I differentiate that with respect to $x_k$, I get
$$
\mu_k = \mu^0_k + RT(\log x_k + 1)
$$
and not the usual expression for the chemical potential in an ideal solution, which is
$$
\mu_k = \mu^0_k + RT\log x_k.
$$
On the other hand, if I would take the free energy to be
$$
G(x) = \sum_k x_k\mu^0_k + RT\sum_k x_k(\log x_k - 1)
$$
then I would get the expected formula for the chemical potential.

So what's going on here? Is Kondepudi and Prigogine's formula for the free energy incorrect or am I making a conceptual mistake somewhere?

(One slight thing I'm unsure of: Kondepudi and Prigogine actually use $\mu^*$ instead of $\mu^0$ in this formula. But I think the idea is that $\mu^*=\mu^0$ for an ideal solution. Certainly I've seen this formula with $\mu^0$ instead of $\mu^*$ before.)

Comment: Your definition is incorrect.  Chemical potential is the partial derivative of G with respect to the number of moles of a species, holding T, P, and number of moles of all other species constant.  You have replaced the number of moles of the various species with mole fraction.  in terms of mole fraction, you third equation is correct.

Comment: @ChetMiller that sounds like it might be the beginnings of an answer. However, I haven't knowingly used mole fractions anywhere - my $x_k$'s are supposed to be numbers of moles. Can you point to where I've implicitly used mole fractions instead?

Comment: Well the equations should be $$\mu_k=\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_k}$$ and $$\mu_k=\mu_k^0+RT\ln{\omega_k}$$where $N_k$ s the number of moles of species k and $\omega_k$ is the mole fraction of species k

Comment: @ChetMiller so when you said "in terms of mole fraction, you third equation is correct," did you mean to say "in terms of mole number"? Then it would make sense to me.

Comment: No, I meant what I said.

Comment: @ChetMiller your second comment contradicts your first one, so I assume you meant what you said in one of them but not the other. It would be helpful to know which one.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction if, in your 3rd equation, xk is mole fraction.